# how to return array of objects as observable in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular7

I am working on a practice of todoApp in angular 7
in which i store todos to local-storage and CRUD functionality.
First i was storing it as array in local-storage but it dont works in all component so i am now trying to returning as observable but i dont know how to do that, any help how to return it as observable will be appreciated.

storage.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from './todo';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageService {

  private todos = new BehaviorSubject(Todo);

  constructor() { }

  public setTodos(todos: Todo[]): void {
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify({ todos: todos }))
  }

  public getTodos(){
    let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    if(localStorageItem == null){
        return [];
    }else{
        return localStorageItem.todos;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried

```
private todos = new BehaviorSubject(Todo);
public setTodos(todos: Todo[]): void {
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify({ todos: this.todos }))
}
```

But it gave error.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: ___it gave error___ what is the error?

Comment: ERROR in ./src/app/storage.service.ts 15:46
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:46)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var StorageService = /** @class */ (function () {
|     function StorageService() {
>         this.todos = new BehaviorSubject(Todo[]);
|     }
|     StorageService.prototype.setTodos = function (todos) {
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: How to store observable instead array in localstorage that i want to do.

Comment: There is absolutely no point in storing an Observable in localstorage. Using `localstorage`, you can only really store strings, such as serialized JSON. What is the reason you want to store an Observable?

Comment: I want to use that single array of objects in all components as if i deletes single todo from one component it oly reflects after a refresh as the component that is displaying all todos are not aware of 
Thats the reason to use observable and subscription
But as i am totally not aware of rxjs i dont know how to implement it

Comment: OK, well don't store the data as an Observable. Store the data as a JSON array, and use an Observable once you've loaded the data if you need.

Comment: Thank you so much
Can you please give me idea how can i get getTodos as observable to use it!
In all component

Comment: You can use `of(this.todos)` (using `import { of } from 'rxjs'`) to return an Observable, however you need a way of emitting a new value from that Observable each time an item is removed / added. You can't just use `splice` in one component and expect every component to get the update

Comment: Ok i got so much idea from your support
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This comes late but in hope to help someone..
You can return `Observable`  in below format using `of()` from `rxjs`

> Emit variable amount of values in a sequence and then emits a complete notification
>
> of() accepts any type of data - any | []
>
> signature: `of(...values, scheduler: Scheduler): Observable`

doc - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of

Example -

```
public getContract(contractId: number): Observable<Contract> {
    const url = `${this._baseUrl}/contracts`;
    // TODO remove on api implementation
    return of(JSON.parse(Data.DUMMY_CONTRACT));
/*
 * below code in uncommented when api is implemented
    return this.http.get<Contract>(url).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('Get Contract:'))
    );
*/
  }
```